# IOS: pickerView crashing on eleventh item

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am populating a pickerView from an array.  It loads into the page okay.  However, when you scroll through the choices of the pickerView at the 11th choice, it crashes with a `[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19fc50490` error.

I really have no idea what to try next and would be grateful for any suggestions:

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return _actnames.count;//THis logs as 30 as there are 30 possibilities
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSLog(@"before crash");  //last line to display before crash
          return _actnames[row];
    }

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    _selectedActName = ([_actnames objectAtIndex:row]);
}
```

The last method is the one where it appears to crash.  As mention, it crashes when you select the 11th item, though there are 30.

Thanks for any ideas.

Update:

```
This is method that pulls actnames from core data:

- (id) getActNames{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Activities"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];
    NSError *error      = nil;
    self.managedObjectContext = [Model sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

    NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   error:&error];
    NSMutableArray * actnames = [[results valueForKey:@"actname"] mutableCopy];
    return actnames;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. To debug the issue, I'd set an exception breakpoint in Xcode, and see where exactly does the error occur.

This answer explains how to set an exception breakpoint : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: Did you parse some JSON to fill your `_actnames` array? It has an `NSNull` reference in it.

Comment: Update your question with how you create and populate `_actnames`.

Comment: It sounds like `actnames[11]` is `[NSNull null]`. You need to be prepared for that possibility, I guess.

Comment: When I log out the array as a comma delimited list, I see that there is a NULL, not where it crashes, but a few items later.  {"item1","item2",..."item14","0(NSNull)","item15"} Perhaps this is causing crash.  How would I work around a null value in the array?

Comment: Ok, that was it.  Fixed bug by adding line  [actnames removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];  Thanks everyone!